# server side issue for Push notification in ios

Tags: ios, service, push-notification, connection

Hi I am trying to use push notification in my app and i ma following the engineyard tutorail, and I am struck on the last step, Making the connection! my node agent/_header.js says mac verify error! I dont know what is that. I have tried changing the passPhrase to the password, created a new certificate, p12 file and tried the same. This is the error am getting. I know its been already posted in the forum, but still i couldnt solve it

`c.context.loadPKCS12(pfx);
                ^
Error: mac verify failure
    at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:145:17)
    at Object.exports.connect (tls.js:1331:27)
    at Agent.connect (/Users/AAA/Documents/Po/poservices/node_modules/apnagent/lib/apnagent/agent/live.js:113:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/AAA/Documents/Po/poservices/agent/_header.js:72:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
SIVAs-MacBook-Air:poservices AAA$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found the answer for this.

The issue was I export the file from keychain in the parent of the key.

What needs to be done is Extend our key in keychain from the child(key), and then export it. [image]